# Appium: autoAcceptAlert doesn't work to allow access to all photos on IOS 14

Tags: java, automation, appium, xcuitest

The problem is that in IOS 14 there is a third option of permission of photos and autoAcceptAlerts is clicking 'don't allow' in case of any passed argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved with adding **acceptAlertButtonSelector** to the desired caps:
**Java**

```
driver.setSetting("acceptAlertButtonSelector", "**/XCUIElementTypeButton[label == 'Allow While Using App']");
```

**Python**

```
"acceptAlertButtonSelector": "**/XCUIElementTypeButton[label == 'Allow While Using App']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Appium [Settings API](http://appium.io/docs/en/advanced-concepts/settings/): for iOS it has `acceptAlertButtonSelector` parameter you need to set via API call and then you can try to find the button with required label:

Allows to customize accept alert button selector.
It helps you to handle an arbitrary element as accept button in accept alert
command. The selector should be a valid class chain expression, where the
search root is the alert element itself.

The default button location algorithm is used if the provided selector is wrong
or does not match any element. e.g.,

```
**/XCUIElementTypeButton[`label CONTAINS[c] 'accept'`]
```